# Filtering collections with simple domain specific languages

Tags: java, pojo

I need the ability to filter a list of POJOs to have filter out items I don't care about.

They're basically streams of POJOs...

Say we have a stream of User objects with firstName, lastName, telephone, zipcode.

I would want a simple expression like:

firstName = 'John'

and obviously this would only match objects which have that field.

It would be ideal if we could do boolean logic such as:

(firstName = 'John' or firstName = 'Allen') and lastName = 'Smith'

I want the language to NOT support loops or arbitrary Java code.

For example.Someone could just submit while(true) {} ... which would DoS a server.

Further, functions and calling into the standard library isn't acceptable either.  Otherwise they can submit System.exit(1).

The filtering language used in wireshark is nice:

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html

> tcp port 23 and not src host 10.0.0.5

... but I need something in Java.

Comment: Why not write the filter in Java.

Comment: You can use LambdaJ it's very readable

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Mule Query Language](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-mule-query-language/) and [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/)

Mule example:

```
List<User> users = ...;

Map<String,Object> context = new HashMap<String,Object>();
context.put("users", users);

Collection<User> result = 
    Query.execute("from users where division = 'Engineering'", context);
```

JXPath example:

```
Address address = (Address)JXPathContext.newContext(vendor).
     getValue("locations[address/zipCode='90210']/address");
```

Comment: ah.. nice.  JXPath looks cool.  Why didn't I see that before.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks for the reminder. I added the relevant examples.